# How to increment the value of a total bye array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know it is a noob question, but still thought of asking out of curiosity.
I have a byte array of 3 bytes for example `[00,00,00]`. everytime I iterate a method I have increment the last by by `0x02` times. Now once the last byte reaches the threshold value `FF` I need to increment the last but one byte to +1 along with incrementing last byte. For example for byte array values `[00,00,FF]` incrementing it with `0x02` should become `[00,01,02]` and finally it should reach `[FF,FF,FF]` what should be the ideal way of doing it rather than using the normal if conditions.

Comment: where does the 0x02 come from?  Usually going from `00,00,FF` by +2 would result in `00,01,01`, not `00,01,00`

Comment: sorry that was a typo. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: and when it hits the limit, should is reset back through zero?  [it's still wrong in the question, BTW]

Comment: It's still unclear what you're asking then.  Your requirement _kind of_ looks like you're representing a large multi-byte integer as lots of individual bytes, but your examples aren't 100% consistent with that.

Comment: @ravoorinandan: near the end it will be like `00,00,FE`. The `0x02` increment will make it `00,01,00`. The last case will be `FE,FE,FE`

Comment: @oliverpool FF,FF,FF

Comment: @ravoorinandan actually `FF,FF,FE`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a for loop and a if condition ?

You cycle through your elements. If the element is smaller than `0xFF`, you increment it, and you return. Otherwise you set it to `0x00` and you let the for loop cycle further.

Pseudo-code:

```
for element in array (in reverse order):
  if(element == 0xFF):
    element = 0
  else:
    element += 0x02
    return array
```

Answer (score 0):

you should work with only one variable

```
var i=0; // from 0 to 4096

//every time you can increment i++;

where you want result just convert i to array like :
function convert_array(val){
  var val2 = parseInt(val/4096, 16);
  var val1 = parseInt(val2/256, 16);
  var val0 = parseInt(val2%256, 16);
  return [val2 , val1, val0];
}


var result = convert_array(i);
```

the advanges :

1. to increment number no problem just i++;
2. you have no loops (for)   :)

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT** *(dumped the nested loops)*

For a more generic approach (obviously not with colors), you should try a cascading increment like this:

```
// non-destructive increment of the arr
// [0xFF, 0x00] -> [0x00, 0x02]
function incremented(arr) {
  var value, 
      index = 0,
      increment = 0x02,
      threshold = 0xFF, 
      re = [],
      flip = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    value = arr[i];
    if (flip === false) {
      // don't touch, just add it
      re.push(value);
    } else if (value + increment > threshold) {
      // add zero value, but keep on flipping
      re.push(0);
    } else {
      // add incremented value
      re.push(value + increment);
    }
  }
  if (flip) {
    // if even the last number did not stop flipping add another
    re.push(increment);
  }
  return re;
}
```

Comment: Why would using hex automatically mean working with colors?

Comment: Does not have to be colors, just said it looks like that

Comment: Yes I have requirement of bytearray whose length is greater than 8.

Comment: @ravoorinandan That comment makes your question unclear, can you please edit to explain what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @Nit if anything that makes it clearer - it reinforces that the value of 3 given in the question was just an example, and that nested loops are absolutely not the answer.

Comment: @Tharabas you appear to be incrementing the bytes in the wrong order

Comment: @Alnitak, correct, but that could be fixed by reversing the array ad lib.